# href syntax for a button (HTML)

Tags: html, href

I have created a button, as shown below. Now I am working on linking it.
However the href part seems to be out of order. Does anyone know how to link
the button to a site (use https://aol.com).
Thank you

```
<body>
    <div class="result15823794" style="width: 160px; height: 30px;     background-image:     url(&quot;http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png&quot    ;);
    " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button76804217.png)'
    " onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png)'">
    <div style="background-image:     url(http://static1.grsites.com/images/0.gif); 
    width: 160px; height: 30px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Really close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick="location.href='https://aol.com/';"`

Sample:

```html
<body>
  <div onclick="location.href='https://aol.com/';" class="result15823794" style="width: 160px; height: 30px;     background-image:     url(&quot;http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png&quot    ;);
        " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button76804217.png)'
        " onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png)'" onclick="location.href='https://aol.com/';">
    <div style="background-image:     url(http://static1.grsites.com/images/0.gif); 
        width: 160px; height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You rock @Chris Happy. This syntax works. I do appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the outmost div with an anchor containing the href to AOL like this:

```html
<a href="https://aol.com/"><div class="result15823794" style="width: 160px; height: 30px;     background-image:     url(&quot;http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png&quot    ;);
    " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button76804217.png)'
    " onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png)'">
    <div style="background-image:     url(http://static1.grsites.com/images/0.gif); 
    width: 160px; height: 30px;"></div>
    </div></a>
```

Comment: Just FYI, it's not valid HTML to wrap block elements like `<div>` in inline-level elements like `<a>` (even though a lot of sites do it).

Comment: Thanks @nineusa. I ran this code, but it did not show the button on my site

Comment: You're welcome - strange though it worked for me in Chrome OSX - it's ok I actually think Chris' answer s the right one, take care ;)

Comment: Yes Benjamin you're right thanks the divs can be changed to a span tag and make everything valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://aol.com" target="_blank">
```

add this after the body the `<body>` tag, then add the closing of the anchor tag before the closing `</body>` tag. Just like my code below.

```
<body>
    <a href="https://aol.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="result15823794" style="width: 160px; height: 30px;     background-image:     url(&quot;http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png&quot    ;);
    " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button76804217.png)'
    " onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage =     'url(http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/button84799376.png)'">
    <div style="background-image:     url(http://static1.grsites.com/images/0.gif); 
    width: 160px; height: 30px;"></div>
    </div>
    </a>
</body>
```